# How to get multiple sites working on Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

I successfully set up a site on Ubuntu with Nginx, but now I want to add a second site to the server. The first site has SSL via Let's Encrypt, but the second won't have SSL. Right now all I can get to display is the first site at two different URIs. Where did I go wrong? I have two sites in my /sites-enabled/ folder.

The first site (the one that works):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220;

    root /var/www/example1.com/web;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html

    server_name example1.com www.example1.com;
    include hhvm.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    location ~* /\.\./ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
}
```

The second site under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;

    resolver 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220;

    root /var/www/example2.com/web;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html

    server_name example2.com www.example2.com;
    include hhvm.conf;
    include global/wordpress.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    location ~* /\.\./ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that your actual domain is not `example2.com`, i.e. that your server name shall not be `server_name example2.com www.example2.com;` but something matching your actual domain.

Comment: You have a `return 301` at the top of your server block.

Comment: @grochmal You're right that my domain is not example2.com. I replaced my actual domain for the question